# Как упростить линейную регрессию: только узнать + или - тренд?

Tags: алгоритм, статистика, статический-анализ

Есть набор данных. Нужно понять, положительный или отрицательный коэффициент у прямой, к которой этот набор апроксимируется.

Кто не поленился пройти Machine Learning на CourseEra, подкиньте решение, пжлст? Не осилю сейчас въезжать во всю математику регрессий, сроки горят.

Поскольку не нужна точность, достаточно определить знак коэффициента, наверное, существует простой алгоритм?

Comment: Можно попробовать параллельно спросить на разделе математики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для задачи подошел [коэффициент Пеарсона](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)